# How do I parse this Xml to an Array - Android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, google-maps

Hey I'm trying to parse this URL: http://webservice.recruit.co.jp/hotpepper/gourmet/v1/?key=899d70a29e983f4b&lat=33.58724&lng=130.3986&range=5&order=4
into my Program, for now it would be enough if i could receive the entires name_kana and lat and lng. I want to put these in an array that i can use to create a "for loop"  to place markers on a google map (different .java file).
How can I do so? Help would really be welcome.

Code:
    public class HandleXml {

```
    private String feldname[] = new String[10];     //Declaring arrays with the Size 10, the API offers 10 entries
    private String lat[] = new String[10];  
    private String lng[] = new String[10];  
    private String budget[] = new String[10];   

       public int x = 0;                            //Counter for the arrays
       public int f = 0;
       public int a = 0;
       public int n = 0;
       public int b = 0;

    private String urlString = null;                
    public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;
       private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;

       public HandleXml(String url)                     //Log.e's are used for easier Debugging
       {Log.e("a","a");
          this.urlString = url;
       }
       public String[] getFeldName()                    //Methods returning the values from the XML to the MainActivity
       {Log.e("b","b");
           return feldname;
       }
       public String[] getLat()
       {Log.e("c","c");
           return lat;
       }
       public String[] getLng()
       {Log.e("d","d");
           return lng;
       }
       public String[] getBudget()
       {Log.e("e","e");
           return budget;
       }
       public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser)  throws XmlPullParserException, IOException       //See name
       {
              Log.e("f","f");
              int event;
              int num=0;
              String text=null;
              Log.e("g","g");

              try 
              {
                  Log.e("h","h");
                  event = myParser.getEventType();                      //Get Event-Type          

              //  for (int i = 0; i < 122; i++) 

                  while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
                  {
                     Log.e(""+num,""+num);
                     Log.e("i","i");
                     String name=myParser.getName();

                    if (name != null)
                        {Log.e("iu"+name,name);}
                    Log.e("j","j");

                    switch (event)                                      //React to the different events
                    {

                       case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                       break;
                       case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                       text = myParser.getText();
                       break;

                       case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                          if(name.equals("name_kana"))
                          {
                              Log.e("k","k");
                              feldname[f] = text;
                              Log.e("adf"+feldname[f], feldname[f]);
                              f++;

                          }
                          else if(name.equals("lat"))
                          {     
                              Log.e("l","l");
                              lat[a] = text;// myParser.getAttributeValue(null,"value");
                              Log.e("lat",lat[a]);
                              a++;
                          }
                          else if(name.equals("lng"))
                          {     
                              Log.e("m","m");
                              lng[n] = text;// myParser.getAttributeValue(null,"value");
                              Log.e("lng",lng[n]);
                              n++;
                          }
                          else if(name.equals("name"))
                          {     
                              Log.e("n","n");
                              budget[b] =text;// myParser.getAttributeValue(null,"value");
                              Log.e(budget[b],budget[b]);
                              b++;

                          }
                          else
                          {}
                          break;
                    }   

                    num++;
                    event = myParser.next();

                 }
                 Log.e("p","p");
                         parsingComplete = false;

              } catch (Exception e) {
                 //e.printStackTrace();
              }

           }

       public void fetchXML()
       {
              Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
              {
                 @Override
                 public void run() 
                 {
                    try 
                    {
                       URL url = new URL(urlString);
                       HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) 
                       url.openConnection();                                        
                         conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                         conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                         conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                          conn.setDoInput(true);
                          conn.connect();
                    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
                    xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

                    myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES
                    , false);
                    myparser.setInput(stream, null);
                    parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
                    stream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            thread.start(); 


           }

        }
```

And this is in the MainActivity:

```
 public void open(View view)  
{

      obj = new HandleXml(url);

      obj.fetchXML();

      while(obj.parsingComplete);

      feldname = obj.getFeldName();

      budget = obj.getBudget();

      lat2 = obj.getLat();
      lng2 = obj.getLng();

      int min = feldname.length;                                        //Set min to lowest length of any Array
      if (min > budget.length)
      {min = budget.length;}
      if (min > lat2.length)
      {min = lat2.length;}
      if (min > lng2.length)
      {min = lng2.length;}
      String aus;
        Log.e("länge", aus = String.valueOf(feldname.length));          //Array Length is 10

      for(int x = 0; x < feldname.length; x++){                         //Reading the Content of the Array for debug purpose
         if (feldname[x] != null)
         { Log.e("feldname", feldname[x]);


         }}


      Log.e("wtgs"+budget.length,"wtgs"+budget.length);                 //Further content reading for the Log
      Log.e("wtgs"+lng2.length,"wtgs"+lng2.length);

      for (int i =0; i < min; i++ )                                     //Placing Markers with Array Contents
      {
      Log.e("6","6");
    //  feldname = obj.getFeldName();
      Log.e("7","7");
    //  
      lat4 = lat2[i];
      lng4 = lng2[i];
      lat3 = Float.parseFloat(lat4);
      lng3 = Float.parseFloat(lng4);

      Log.e("10","10");

  GoogleMap mMap;
      Log.e("11","11");
      mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1)).getMap();
      Log.e("12","12");
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(lat3, lng3))
        .title(feldname[i]+" "+budget[i]));  
      Log.e("13","13"); 
      }
}
```

Further Information, thats of my HandleXml class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.util.Log;
```

LogCat

```
02-04 16:24:49.515: W/ActivityManager(2350): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) } U=0: not found
02-04 16:24:49.520: W/GAV2(30695): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Service unavailable (code=1), will retry.
02-04 16:24:50.555: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(30903): Could not load Finalizer in its own class loader. Loading Finalizer in the current class loader instead. As a result, you will not be able to garbage collect this class loader. To support reclaiming this class loader, either resolve the underlying issue, or move Google Collections to your system class path.
02-04 16:24:50.555: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(30903): java.io.FileNotFoundException: com/google/inject/internal/util/$Finalizer.class
02-04 16:24:50.555: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(30903):   at com.google.inject.internal.util.$FinalizableReferenceQueue$DecoupledLoader.getBaseUrl(SourceFile:269)
02-04 16:24:50.555: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(30903):   at com.google.inject.internal.util.$FinalizableReferenceQueue$DecoupledLoader.loadFinalizer(SourceFile:253)
02-04 16:24:50.555: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(30903):   at com.google.inject.internal.util.$FinalizableReferenceQueue.loadFinalizer(SourceFile:175)
02-04 16:24:50.555: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(30903):   at com.google.inject.internal.util.$FinalizableReferenceQueue.<clinit>(SourceFile:100)
02-04 16:24:50.555: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(30903):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
02-04 16:24:50.555: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(30903):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
02-04 16:24:50.555: W/nalizableReferenceQueue(30903):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 16:24:50.835: W/ActivityManager(2350): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10044
02-04 16:24:50.835: W/ActivityManager(2350): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10044
02-04 16:24:50.910: W/ActivityManager(2350): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10044
02-04 16:24:50.910: W/ActivityManager(2350): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10044
02-04 16:24:50.940: W/ActivityManager(2350): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10044
02-04 16:24:50.945: W/ActivityManager(2350): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=10044
```

Skipped some Parts because of the map i have to debug on a real device, lot's of entries... but no real error regardinbg the program

Comment: post the code what you tried.then only you get better solution.

Comment: what parser are you using?>

Comment: Tried Debugging the program but simply stops after 123 runs trough the switch event (nothing special on this point in the xml)

Comment: @user3196789 post the stacktrace. does it crash and which parser are you using?

Comment: Android Launch!
adb is running normally.
Performing com.example.xmlparser.MainActivity activity launch
Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-02-04 16:20:31 - GeoLocation] Uploading GeoLocation.apk onto device '4df1ae633aae5f45'
Installing GeoLocation.apk... Success!
Starting activity com.example.xmlparser.MainActivity on device 4df1ae633aae5f45
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.xmlparser/.MainActivity }

Comment: @user3196789 post the logcat by editing your post. It has details reagarding the crash

Comment: @user3196789 what is line 123 your parsing looks fine

Comment: @Raghunandan <sp>
http://www.hotpepper.jp/strJ001010265/scoupon/?vos=nhppalsa000016
</sp>
</coupon_urls>
also when i set the number off "runs" to 122 it works but then cant display more than one additional marker and especially displaying many is importend

Comment: @user3196789 i tried your code and i guess you ahve over 900 entries. you can display the markers using a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a Http get request to get the data from the url first.

Then use any xml parser to parse the tags and get the required data.

For parsing you can use `XmlPullParser` or a parser of your choice. Once you parse you can add it to array or arraylist

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Note: All network operations should be done in a background thread.

Use `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`. You can also use a library called `Volley`.

Edit:

Your parsing looks fine. I tried your code. You can have arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();  
ArrayList<String> budList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<String> latList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<String> lngList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then

```
public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser)  throws XmlPullParserException, IOException       //See name
    {
           Log.e("f","f");
           int event;
           int num=0;
           String text=null;
           Log.e("g","g");
           try 
           {
               Log.e("h","h");
               event = myParser.getEventType();                         
               //  for (int i = 0; i < 122; i++) 
               while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
               {
                  // Log.e(""+num,""+num);
                  // Log.e("i","i");
                  String name=myParser.getName();

                 if (name != null)
                 {
                    // Log.e("iu"+name,name);
                 }
                 switch (event)                                    
                 {

                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    break;
                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = myParser.getText();
                    break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                      String lat =null,bud=null,lng=null,nam=null;;
                       if(name.equals("name_kana"))
                       {
                          budList.add(text);

                       }
                       else if(name.equals("lat"))
                       {     
                           latList.add(text);
                       }
                       else if(name.equals("lng"))
                       {     
                           lngList.add(text);
                       }
                       else if(name.equals("name"))
                       {     
                           nameList.add(text);
                       }
                       else
                       {

                       }


                       break;
                 }  

                 num++;
                 event = myParser.next();

               }  

           } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }

        }
```

Comment: having problems using the "entry.get(0).getFeldName" might be stupid but i receive the error "entry can not be resolved", when i change it to "Entry" i get an error saying "create class get(int) in Entry.java"

Comment: @user3196789 use the edited code. all separate lists for each of them. Now loop through the lists add do whatever is necessary. Works fine

Comment: sorry never worked with arraylist before, where do i put "ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>(); " in the code?

Comment: @Inside your class outside of the methods. This is basic java stuff. So pls make sure you learn those before coding